# Change IntelliJ suggestion list shortcuts

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

How to change up/down motion through suggestion list keys from **Up/Down cursor keys** to e.g. **Ctrl-P/Ctrl-N**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add these shortcuts in *Settings/Keymap*. Look for these items:

- Editor Actions/Up
- Editor Actions/Down

And for each add Keyboard shortcut you want (besides the default Up and Down) arrows by right clicking on the action and selecting *Add Keyboard Shortcut*.

This will however cause that these shortcuts for Up and Down will work not only in suggestion lists such as autocomplete results, but also in editor. I don't think there is an option to change these bindings for suggestion lists only.